# Using Lucee Server with Command Box problems accessing Server Administration page

Tags: server, datasource, cfml, lucee, commandbox

I recently downloaded CommandBox to try to set up a Lucee Server. I have a folder called LuceeSever with an Index.cfm page. When I type the command "box server start" it opens a window at this address: http://127.0.0.1:54613 displaying my index.cfm page. Cool.

But I would like to connect a datasource and I would like to do this thorough the server admin panel that everyone else says to use. So when I try to access http://127.0.0.1:54613/lucee/admin/server.cfm I get this screen:

[image]

So I created a password.txt file that contains 1 line of plaintext that is the password I wanted to use. So my directory looks like this:

```
LuceeServer>
    index.cfm
    password.txt
```

In which index.cfm and password.txt are at the same level. When I click import file the screen reloads and nothing happens.

I assume I have things set up incorrectly. I've never used commandbox before and I dont really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `password.txt` needs to go in the "root Lucee server directory", which isn't the same as your site's web root (which wouldn't be a very secure place to put it). In CommandBox the location is a bit obscure, but you can find it with the following command:

```
server info property=serverHomeDirectory
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is super useful. The problem was I couldn't find it.

Comment: For added clarity, you need to run that command at the CommandBox prompt, not just the command prompt.

Answer (score 7):

You can bypass this entirely by using [CFConfig](https://cfconfig.ortusbooks.com/). You can either specify the `adminPassword` in your `.cfconfig.json` file

```
{
  "adminPassword":"myPass"
}
```

or you can install [commandbox-dotenv](https://www.forgebox.io/view/commandbox-dotenv) and set a [global `.env` file](https://github.com/commandbox-modules/commandbox-dotenv#global-env-file) that has a `cfconfig_adminPassword` key.

**~/.box.env**

```
# Add environment variables to be loaded into CommandBox when it starts
# Variables are in the form of foo=bar, one per line
cfconfig_adminPassword=myPass
```

Disclaimer: I am the lead developer of CommandBox and the CFConfig module.

Answer (score 5):

When you run your server with CommandBox, click on its tray icon in the right corner of your desktop, click `open` and then the `server home` folder like shown on the image below:

[image: CommandBox Tray Icon Navigation to Server Home]

Then navigate to  `/WEB-INF/lucee-server/context/` and place your password.txt file there. Then go back to lucees server admin page in your browser and click the "import file" button to import the password.txt file.

Comment: Thanks. Glad it worked. There are many ways in getting this job done. The other answers are better suited for automated environments. Just choose the one that works best for you and enjoy!